# How to extract 3rd element of the list in Scala

Tags: scala

```
 def third_list[A](ls: List[A]): A = {
     // Code can be changed here
    return List(ls(2)) //Error line for return type
  }


  val l1 = List(1, 2, 3, 4)
  println(third_list(l1))
  println(third_list(List(1,2,(3,4,5), 6, 7)))
```

I need to return 3rd element of the list following the return type criteria.

I am getting type mismatch error:

> Required A found list[A]

Shouldn't ls(2) return an element type already?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The simple answer to the question is to use `lift`:

```
def third_list[A](ls: List[A]): Option[A] =
  ls.lift(2)
```

This returns an `Option` because you really want your code to work even if the list doesn't have three elements. Process the data inside the `Option` or use `getOrElse` to specify a default.

Comment: This is great :) Very concise, never new about `lift`! Could you provide a link to its definition? I've searched https://github.com/scala/scala with no luck.

Comment: The best place to look is the documentation for the Standard Library [here](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/immutable/List.html#lift:A=%3EOption[B])

Comment: For a little more background, `lift` is available on `List` because `List` (eventually) mixes in `PartialFunction`, which defines `lift` as returning `Option`, returning a `Some` where its `apply` function is defined for its input, and `None` otherwise, rather than throwing a match not found exception.

Answer (score 2):

You are returning a List with elements of type A therefore you are returning a List[A] value, but the return type you have set for that method is A and they do not match.

Answer (score 2):

You have declared the return type of `third_list` as `A`, but you are extracting an element of type `A` (`ls(2)`), wrapping it in a new list (`List(ls(2))`, and returning that instead. Also, your code will fail if there aren't at least 3 elements in your list. One way to handle that could be to return an `Option[A]` rather than an `A`. Something like the following:

```scala
def third_list[A](ls: List[A]): Option[A] = ls match {
  case _ :: _ :: third :: _ =>
    Some(third)
  case _ =>
    None
}
```

---

##### Edit:

Using `Option` to handle the scenario where the third element isn't present is the ideal approach as it tells the caller of this method that it cannot be guarateed to return a value of `A`.

If, however, you have to keep the original method signature you could throw an exception in the event that a third element is not present:

```scala
def third_list[A](ls: List[A]): A = ls match {
  case _ :: _ :: third :: _ =>
    third
  case _ =>
    throw new RuntimeException(s"Error occurred access third element of list. List had length ${ls.length}.")
}
```

Alternatively could ask the caller of method to provide a default value in the event a third element is no accessible, though in this scenario you are again changing the method signature, and therefore `Option` is recommended:

```scala
def third_list[A](ls: List[A], default: => A): A = ls match {
  case _ :: _ :: third :: _ =>
    third
  case _ =>
    default
}
```

It worth repeating that having the return type be of type `Option` is still the best practice approach. [See this official Scala lang documentation on functional error handling](https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/scala-book/functional-error-handling.html).

Comment: The existing code already throws an exception on error so not really much improvement to do it manually. Either way it is not functional so best avoided.